# ¿Como puedo hacer que en el menu desplegable se muestre una opcion dependiendo de la hora y los minutos?

Tags: javascript, html

En lo que necesito ayuda es a la hora de mostrar las opciones de tiempo, solo se ejecutan las 2 primeran condiciones de IF

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<!--Esto hace que se cree una lista con los horarios-->
  <select name="custom_type" id="time" onfocusin="timeSlot()" class="elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save" data-type="extra"
    type="custom_type" data-custom-type="Webinar Time">
    <option value="0">Select Your Time</option>
    <option value="1">12:00 AM</option>
    <option value="2">12:30 AM</option>
    <option value="3">1:00 AM</option>
    <option value="4">1:30 AM</option>
    <option value="5">2:00 AM</option>
    <option value="6">2:30 AM</option>
    <option value="7">3:00 AM</option>
    <option value="8">3:30 AM</option>
    <option value="9">4:00 AM</option>
    <option value="10">4:30 AM</option>
    <option value="11">5:00 AM</option>
    <option value="12">5:30 AM</option>
    <option value="13">6:00 AM</option>
    <option value="14">6:30 AM</option>
    <option value="15">7:00 AM</option>
    <option value="16">7:30 AM</option>
    <option value="17">8:00 AM</option>
    <option value="18">8:30 AM</option>
    <option value="19">9:00 AM</option>
    <option value="20">9:30 AM</option>
    <option value="21">10:00 AM</option>
    <option value="22">10:30 AM</option>
    <option value="23">11:00 AM</option>
    <option value="24">11:30 AM</option>
    <option value="25">12:00 PM</option>
   
  </select>
  <div class="form-group">

    <script type="text/javascript">

//todo este codigo esconde las opciones

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[0].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[1].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[2].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[3].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[4].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[5].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[6].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[7].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[8].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[9].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[10].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[11].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[12].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[13].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[14].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[15].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[16].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[17].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[18].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[19].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[20].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[21].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[22].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[23].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[24].style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[25].style.display = 'none';

//esto se supone que muestra la opcion correspondiente a la hora del dia (aqui //es donde nececito ayuda)
// ignoren esto(jdshfojhsdfohsdofjhsdofhsdofhoñsdjfhoñsdjfhñosjdhhhhfhfhfhfjfhdfhj bndjnvj bn)
      function timeSlot() {

        var hour = new Date().getHours();
        var minutes = new Date().getMinutes();


        if (hour = 0, minutes <= 29) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[2].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 0, minutes >= 30) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[3].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 1, minutes <= 29) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[4].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 1 && minutes >= 30) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[5].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 2, minutes <= 29) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[6].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 2 && minutes >= 30) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[7].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 3, minutes <= 29) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[8].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 3, minutes >= 30) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[9].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 4, minutes <= 29) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[10].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 4, minutes >= 30) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[11].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 5, minutes <= 29) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[12].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 5, minutes >= 30) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[13].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 6, minutes <= 29) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[14].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 6, minutes >= 30) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[15].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 7, minutes <= 29) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[16].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 7, minutes >= 30) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[17].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 8, minutes <= 29) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[18].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 8, minutes >= 30) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[19].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 9, minutes <= 29) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[20].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 9, minutes >= 30) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[21].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 10, minutes <= 29) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[22].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 10, minutes >= 30) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[23].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 11, minutes <= 29) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[24].style.display = 'block';

        } else if (hour = 11, minutes >= 30) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[25].style.display = 'block';

        }  else if (hour = 23, minutes >= 30) {

          document.getElementsByClassName("elInput elSelectInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputMid elInputStyl0 elInputBG1 elInputBR5 elInputI0 elInputIBlack elInputIRight elInput-Select1 ceoinput required1 garlic-auto-save")[0].options[1].style.display = 'block';

        }
      }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas en tu condicional `if()`, la primera es que si quieres comparar la variable `hour` debe ser un doble `==` asi `hour==0`, de lo contrario asignas a la variable el valor.

El segundo problema viene con la `','` dentro del `if()`, ya que esta se usa para separar y evaluar de izquierda a derecha, devolviendo siempre el ultimo valor. es decir lo que haces es asignar **0** a la variable `hour` y evaluar la ultima condición solamente y la asignación se hará independientemente del resultado, deberías poner `&&` en su lugar para indicar el **AND**.

Mira estos ejemplos:

```js
// supongamos que las funciones devuelven esto :

        var hour = 0
        var minutes = 28;


        if (hour = 1, minutes <= 29) // aqui la consola muestra 1 por que es true la ultima evaluacion 
          console.log(hour);
```

En el primer ejemplo la segunda condición se cumple y despliega `1` en la consola, y en este segundo ejemplo no se cumple y no entra a la condicional pero aun así se hace la asignación.

```js
// supongamos que las funciones devuelven esto :

            var hour = 0
            var minutes = 30;


            if (hour = 1, minutes <= 29) // en este caso la condicion es false pero se asigna el valor 1 de todas formas 
              console.log(hour+"No se muestra este resultado por que la condicion es falsa");
              
              console.log(hour+" se asigna '1' a la variable independientemente del resultado");
```

Toma esto en cuenta y has los cambios para que funcione, es por esto que nunca pasa del segundo `if()` .

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba.
lo que pasa es que aun soy un novato y me ayudaste mucho en mi aprendizaje, de verdad te lo agradezco.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno medio difícil trabajar con tantas variables sueltas.

realice el siguiente código resolviendo tu problema, aunque te aconsejaría que cambies los `value` de los `select` y que hagan referencia a las horas, sin embargo realice el código utilizando el texto del select.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* realizamos el ocultamiento de las options*/
        var op = document.getElementById("time");
        for (var i = 1; i < op.length; i++) {
            op[i].style.display="none";
        }

         /* mostramos segun la hora*/
        function timeSlot() {
            var hour = new Date().getHours();
            var minutes = new Date().getMinutes();

            var op = document.getElementById("time");
            for (var i = 1; i < op.length; i++) {
                var  hora = op[i].text.split(':');
                if(hour == hora[0] && minutes >= 30 ){
                    op[i+1].style.display="block";
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    if(hour == hora[0]){
                        op[i].style.display="block";
                        break;
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Remplaza el código que tienes en las etiquetas script y debería funcionar.

saludos!

Comment: Hola, te agradezco mucho tu comentario, pero desafortunadamente lo probé y no me funciono :(  quizá porque aun soy muy novato en JS y no pude entender muy bien el código que me mandaste, pero igual aprecio tu interés :)